# How to join a Flask API with the mongo using only one dockerfile?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to merge the image of an API made in Flask with an image of mongo in a single final image, like the dockerfile below:

```
FROM  mongo:latest

EXPOSE 27017

FROM python:3.8-alpine

ADD requirements.txt .

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ADD api /api
ADD scripts /api/scripts
WORKDIR /api
CMD python api.py &> api.log
```

But it is not working... If I put the API commands in the dockerfile first, only the API image is created. If I put the mongo's commands first, only the image of the mongo is created. I am creating the image in the docker with the following command:

```
docker build --tag api .
```

And I'm creating the container with the following command:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -p 27017:27017 --name api -d api
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I wouldn't recommend this**

I've personally never seen the app and database included together in a single Dockerfile. This would also require you to start 2 processes within one container. If you did want to go down this route, then your issue here is you have a multi-stage Dockerfile, but you've not included anything from your first stage, therefore, you actually only have your python code.

Again, if you did want to go down this route (I highly recommend you don't), then you would call your first stage like so:

```
FROM mongo:latest AS mongo_builder
```

And then proceed to copy from that stage

```
FROM mongo:latest AS mongo_builder

FROM python:3.8-alpine

COPY --from mongo_builder /usr/bin/mongo* /usr/bin/

...
```

Then you can work out how to run 2 processes within a container (which is non-trivial).

However, I wouldn't recommend doing this.

---

**What I would do**

What I would do is scrap the multi-stage build entirely and run 2 separate containers.

Once you figure out how to run your python application in a container (let's call it `myapp` for now), then you can run the 2 containers.

```
docker run -d --name mongo mongo:latest  # (You'll want to figure out how to persist data)
docker run -d --name myapp --link mongo -p 50000:50000 myapp:latest --mongo-host mongo:27017
```

^ This is assuming you have a way to specify the mongo host you want to connect to with `--mongo-host`.

This will use the `--link` option which will allow you to access your `mongo` container's network, which will be referenced by its name (`mongo`).